Why $\int_{-L}^L \int_{-L}^L\frac{|x+y|}{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)} dxdy \approx 4\pi \log L$ as $L\to\infty$?
For $L>0$, consider the integral
$$\int_{-L}^L \int_{-L}^L\frac{|x+y|}{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)} dxdy.$$
Mathematica tells me that this integral can be evaluated in a complicated expression involving polylog functions. It also tells me that as $L\to\infty$, the above expression is asymptotically $4\pi \log L$.
How can I derive this result by a more qualitative argument not involving direct evaluation?

By the way, the asymptotic is $$4 \pi  \log \left(\frac{L}{2}\right)+\frac{8}{L}+\frac{2 \pi }{L^2}-\frac{32}{9 L^3}-\frac{\pi }{L^4}+\frac{184}{75
L^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{L^6}\right)$$

Your integral can be re-written in the form
$$
I(L) = 2\int_0^L \!{\int_0^L {\frac{{\left| {x + y} \right| + \left| {x - y} \right|}}{{(x^2  + 1)(y^2  + 1)}}{\rm d}x}\, {\rm d}y} .
$$
By the Leibniz integral rule,
$$
I'(L) = \frac{4}{{L^2  + 1}}\int_0^L {\frac{{\left| {x + L} \right| + \left| {x - L} \right|}}{{x^2  + 1}}{\rm d}x}  = \frac{{8L}}{{L^2  + 1}}\int_0^L {\frac{{{\rm d}x}}{{x^2  + 1}}}=\frac{{8L\arctan(L)}}{{L^2  + 1}} .
$$
Finally, by L'Hôpital's rule,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{L \to  + \infty } \frac{{I(L)}}{{4\pi \log L}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{L \to  + \infty } \frac{{I'(L)}}{{4\pi /L}} = \frac{2}{\pi }\mathop {\lim }\limits_{L \to  + \infty } \frac{{L^2\arctan(L) }}{{L^2  + 1}}   = \frac{2}{\pi }\frac{\pi}{2}  = 1.
$$

Alternatively one can use $x+y+|x-y| = 2 \max(x, y)$, which leads to $$ I(L) = 8 \int_0^L \int_0^x \frac{x}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}dy dx = 8 \int_0^L \frac{x \arctan(x)}{1+x^2}$$

@MartinR. Why don't you write an answer ? This is a very nice solution (and simple ....after reading it). Cheers :-)

@MartinR. It is not bad at all without L'Hospital (assuming that you accept to deal with a single polylogarithm.

@ClaudeLeibovici "Single" polylogarithm? I am curious on how it can be written by a single polylogarithm, as my trial on Mathematica gives a bunch of ($\geq 10$) terms involving polylogs.

Using the symmetry of the integrand we have (the first step is as in Gary's answer):
$$
\begin{align}
I(L) &= 2\int_0^L \int_0^L \frac{| x + y| + |x - y| }{(x^2  + 1)(y^2  + 1)}\,dx dy \\
&= 4\int_0^L \int_0^L \frac{\max(x, y)}{(x^2  + 1)(y^2  + 1)}\,dx dy \\
&= 8 \int_0^L \int_0^x \frac{x}{(x^2  + 1)(y^2  + 1)} \,dy dx \\
&= 8 \int_0^L \frac{x \arctan(x)}{1+x^2} \, dx \\
&= 8 \int_0^L \frac{x}{1+x^2} \left( \frac \pi 2 - \arctan\left(\frac 1x\right)\right) \, dx \\
&= 2 \pi  \ln(1+L^2) - 8 \int_0^L \frac{x \arctan(1/x)}{1+x^2} \, dx \, .
\end{align}
$$
Using $0 \le \arctan(1/x) \le 1/x$  we can show that the second term on the right-hand side is bounded:
$$
 0 \le \int_0^L \frac{x \arctan(1/x)}{1+x^2} \, dx
\le  \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2} \, dx = \frac \pi 2 \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 I(L) \, \begin{cases}
 \le  2 \pi  \ln(1+L^2) \le 4 \pi \ln(L) + 2 \pi/L^2 \\
\ge 2 \pi  \ln(1+L^2) - 4 \pi \ge 4 \pi \ln(L) -4 \pi
\end{cases}
$$
and in particular
$$
 I(L)  = 4 \pi \ln(L) + O(1)
$$
for $L \to \infty$.

I added an answer based ot tight bounds of the arctangent function and anothe one with the result from Mathematica. All of that thanks to your solution. Cheers :-)

Using @Martin R's comment and solution
$$I=8\int_0^L \frac{x }{x^2+1}\, \tan ^{-1}(x)\,dx$$ From Mathematica
$$J=\int \frac{x }{x^2+1}\, \tan ^{-1}(x)\,dx$$
$$J=-\frac{1}{2} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x+i}{x-i}\right)-\frac{1}{2} i \tan ^{-1}(x)^2-\log\left(\frac{2 i}{-x+i}\right) \tan ^{-1}(x)$$
$$I=-4 i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{L^2+2 i L-1}{L^2+1}\right)-8 \log \left(\frac{2 (1-i
   L)}{L^2+1}\right) \tan ^{-1}(L)-4 i \tan ^{-1}(L)^2-\frac{i \pi ^2}{3}$$ which leads to the asymptotics already given in comments
$$I=4 \pi  \log \left(\frac{L}{2}\right)+\frac{8}{L}+\frac{2 \pi }{L^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{L^3}\right)$$

Using @Martin R's comment and solution
$$I=8\int_0^L \frac{x }{x^2+1}\, \tan ^{-1}(x)\,dx$$
Using, for $x>0$,  the tight bounds given here
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{\frac{4}{\pi ^2}+\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{4}{\pi ^2}\right)^2+\frac{4 }{\pi ^2}x^2}} < \tan^{-1}(x) $$
$$ \tan^{-1}(x) <\frac{x}{\left(1-\frac{6}{\pi ^2}\right)+ \sqrt{\frac{36}{\pi ^4}+\frac{4 }{\pi ^2}x^2}}=g(x)$$ which give
$$\left| \tan ^{-1}(x)-f(x)\right| \lt 0.0026$$
$$\Phi_f=\int_0^\infty \Big({\tan ^{-1}(x)}  - {f(x) }\Big)^2\,dx=1.936\times 10^{-5}$$  and
$$\left| \tan ^{-1}(x)-g(x)\right| \lt 0.0030$$
$$\Phi_g=\int_0^\infty \Big({\tan ^{-1}(x)}  - {g(x) }\Big)^2\,dx=1.356\times 10^{-4}$$
No  problem with the integrals and their asymptotic expansions
$$I_f=8 \int_0^L \frac{x }{x^2+1}\,f(x)\,dx$$
$$I_f= 4\pi \log (L)-\frac{35}{4}+\frac 8L+\frac{\pi ^4-16}{4 \pi  L^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{L^3}\right)$$ and
$$I_g=8 \int_0^L \frac{x }{x^2+1}\,g(x)\,dx$$
$$I_g= 4\pi \log (L)-\frac{173}{20}+\frac{2 \left(\pi ^2-6\right)}{L}+\frac{-18+16 \pi ^2-\pi ^4}{2 \pi  L^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{L^3}\right)$$
The coefficients are almost identical (the constant terms were rationalized; they are good approximations of $-4 \pi  \log (2)$).
